# Data not populating in form upon clicking edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am working on this `ASP.NET MVC` project where I am performing simple `CRUD` operations. On clicking `Edit` button, I want to get the data from the database and populate it in the `Create` View (same view with the help of which I entered the data).

The issue that I have is that, though I am able to enter the data into the database using the `Create.cshtml` view, I am not able to populate the data back into the fields to the same `View` upon clicking `Edit`. On checking, I see that I am able to get the data from the database from the `Controller` and I am sending it to the `View - Create`. But, the fields are not getting populated in the `View`.

Where am I going wrong?

**View - Create.cshtml**

```
<form method="post" action="/Books/Create" id="formBooks">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <div>
                    <label asp-for="Title" class="label">Title</label>
                    <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" required />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label asp-for="Author" class="label">Author</label>
                    <input asp-for="Author" class="form-control" id="author" name="author" required />
                <span asp-validation-for="Author" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                ...

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn bgm-orange waves-effect mybtn">SAVE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller - BooksController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Create(int? Id)
{
    if(Id == null)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        var bookData = _context.Books
            .Where(b => b.ID == Id)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return View(bookData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `bookData` is not null and actually contains data? Change `.FirstOrDefault()` to just `First()`.

Comment: Yes. I verified. It contains the required data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` attribute plays a vital role in binding the data to the `<input></input>` field. Also, `value` attribute gets the value to display in the `Edit` view.

```
<input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter title..." value="@(Model != null ? Model.Title : "")" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Books books= db.Books.Find(id);
        if (books== null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(books);
    }
```

//Try this i hope this will work